# Error when updating Angular 7 -> Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, swagger-codegen, angular8

A month ago I started a Angular 7 project. Now I need to include Angular Material into the project and `npm i` it. It recently came out in a version 8 which seems incompatible with Angular 7.

So I started updating Angular 7 → Angular 8: `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`. This gives me an error:

```
$ng update @angular/cli @angular/core

Package "@ngrx/core" has an incompatible peer dependency to "rxjs" (requires "^5.0.0-beta.12", would install "6.5.2").

Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above.
```

In this guide https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0 I found:

> "Once you and all of your dependencies have updated to RxJS 6, remove
>   rxjs-compat."

I should be on rxjs^6. I need `rxjs-compat` to be able to use my `swagger client` generated with https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen. I tried to remove `"rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2"` from package.json, but no luck.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "fem",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "$(npm bin)/cypress open",
    "e2e-protractor": "ng e2e",
    "swagger-generate": "swagger-codegen generate -i ./swagger.json -l typescript-angular -o ./src/swagger-client"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^7.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.8.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "formdata-polyfill": "^3.0.18",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/date-fns": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "cypress": "^3.3.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

So my goals are:

1. be able to use `Angular Material v8` in the project
2. update to `Angular v8`
3. keep using the generated Swagger client

Comment: Exemplary question!

Comment: I think swagger-codegen can work in Angular 8, although it does require a little help. See [this](https://link.medium.com/KN10VB51wX).

Answer (score 1):

**steps upgrade angular with ngrx**

Uninstall ngrx packages

run command ng update @angular/cli @angular/core

errors will be triggered while migrating angular core packages due to unavailability of ngrx packages

to resolve issues reinstall ngrx packages

run command ng update @angular/core --from 7 --to 8 --migrate-only

Done angular upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You need to abandon the `npm` direct manipulation to upgrade Angular and embrace the new Angular Schematics that does all the required stuff automagically.

Use `ng update` instead and update each package from there, you can update the other libraries with `npm`, but the new paradigm for Angular and it's Libraries is via Schematics .

Embrace their power and develop your own code generators ;)